# Google analytics with Jekyll and Skinny Bones

Tags: google-analytics, jekyll, github-pages, jekyll-bootstrap

I just set up my user site on github and used Jekyll with the Skinny Bones theme. I a having problems to add google analytics to my site.

I obtained the tracking ID and script to embed in my html from Google Analytics and pasted it within the    of the home.html.

```
skinny-bones-jekyll-master
├── _site                               # compiled site ready to deploy
├── _layouts
|    ├── archive.html                   # archive listing of a group of posts or collection
|    ├── article.html                   # articles, blog posts, text heavy material layout
|    ├── default.html                   # base
|    ├── home.html                      # home page
|    └── media.html                     # portfolio, work, media layout
.
.
.
└── index.md                            # homepage content
```

Where index.md is using home.html as layout. 
So far, I can not detect traffic on my site with analytics and I tried already to set the default page in the analytics settings to home.html. No luck. Any ideas?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I looked at your site ([sytpp.github.io](http://sytpp.github.io/), right?) and everything seems to be set up correctly. When I look at the Network requests in Chrome dev tools, I can verify that hits are being sent to Google Analytics.

If this is a new Google Analytics account, you probably just need to wait 24-48 hours before you'll start seeing data in the Google Analytics website.

Answer (score 1):

I just installed google analytics on my skinny bones jekyll site, and it took two days for it to start working.

The confounding part is that Google Analytics has a tracker on their site saying something like "not tracking data". It even gave a time, down to the second, that it claimed it last checked for data. Even though I made no changes, two days later it was tracking data.

For others out there who were impatient like me, just give it time.